# SQL UPDATE with two WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I can't find the error with my SQL command. I keep getting "ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated"

```
UPDATE Customers1
SET CUST_ADDRESS=’57 Jump str’
WHERE CUST_CITY=’Los Angeles’
AND CUST_STATE=’CA’;
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my command?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using straight single quotes? ' would be correct, but not ’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen when your quotes are not straight. Ensure that they are properly formatted. Sometimes when you copy and paste it turns out the way that yours shows, which wouldn't run properly.